# Installing Linux alongside Windows 8 -- have I messed up my partitions?

Tags: windows-8, installation, partitioning, linux-mint

I just bought an [HP Envy h8-1437c](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03517380&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5295996&prodTypeId=12454) desktop computer (Intel Core i5 CPU, 1 TB hard drive, 12 GB memory). It came with Windows 8 pre-installed. I want to run Linux on it, specifically [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) 14.1 Mate, but I'd like to keep the Windows 8 installation.

I configured Windows 8, and that's working just fine. The system has a 20 GB "Recovery Image" partition, presumably usable to reinstall Windows 8.

I copied `linuxmint-14.1-mate-dvd-32bit.iso` to a USB thumb drive using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) (and I just now realized I really wanted the 64-bit version, but that shouldn't be relevant to my current problem), so the thumb drive acts like a live CD. (Linux Mint 14.1 is derived from Ubuntu 12.10.) I had to disable UEFI secure boot to get the system to boot from the USB drive.

I installed Linux Mint alongside Windows 8. The installer let me specify how to partition the drive; I allocated 200 GB to Windows, and the rest to Linux Mint. The installation appeared to finish with no problem.

When I rebooted the system, it booted into Windows. When I rebooted again and went into the boot menu, it didn't show me an option to boot the newly install Linux Mint. I can still boot from the thumb drive.

Now here's the weird thing. When I boot into Windows, it still shows that my Windows C: drive is nearly 2 terabytes. When I boot into Linux Mint with the thumb drive, I see a file system mounted at `/media/mint/2a9d26f4-df0f-4347-800f-817f8fb44051` that's about 1.6 terabytes. Since the entire drive is 2 terabytes, there's obviously an overlap of some sort.

Did the Linux Mint installer fail to set up the partitions correctly? Am I in danger of corrupting data, or of having done so already? Have I hosed my Windows installation? (It still seems to be working, but I haven't done much with it; in particular, I'm trying to to create too many files.)

Given that I installed the wrong version of Linux Mint, I suppose my best first step is to restore the Windows installation to the state it was in before I did the Linux installation. How can I do that?

If necessary, I don't mind reinstalling Windows from the "Recovery Image".

(I've just ordered a second hard drive, and I'm now planning to let Windows have the entire drive and put Linux on the other one. I suspect that will make things easier, but any solutions that let them share the same drive are welcome and may be more helpful to others.)

I have more detailed information if anyone needs it, but this question is already longer than I'd like it to be.

**UPDATE:**

I've mostly solved the problem, though not quite in the way I'd like.

I tried to expand the partition holding the (now smaller) `C:` drive from Windows, but without success. Windows shows a horizontal graph of all the partitions, with the large Linux partition to the right of the `C:` partition. For whatever reason, it lets you expand a partition into free space to its left on that graph, not to its right.

I rebooted with the Linux USB thumb drive, and was able to see all the partitions, including a Grub partition between the `C:` drive and the large Linux partition (that wasn't visible on Windows). I was able to convert the Grub and Linux partitions to free space, but the attempt to expand the Windows `C:` partition into the free space failed with a message about an I/O error -- though it continued apparently running for a day or two after that.

I finally decided to reformat the large Linux partition as NFTS, and use it as an extra logical drive from Windows. Windows initially allocated it as the `K:` drive. After I reinstalled Windows from the recovery partition yet again, now shows up as the `D:` drive (and the recovery partition changed from `D:` to `E:`). I'm content with that layout; in some ways it's probably better than having all of Windows on one huge `C:` drive. For example, if it becomes necessary later I'll be able to reinstall Windows onto the `C:` drive without losing my data on `D:`.

The next step will be to add a second drive (which arrived yesterday) and install Linux on it, giving me (I hope) a dual-boot system.

Installing Windows from the recovery partition didn't give me the option of messing around with the partitions; it just installed it on `C:` without asking.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I know is that installing Linux and Windows, whatever the versions, on the same drive is very possible. You shouldn't need to buy a new hard drive at all.

I wouldn't say I -know- but -think- these things:

-Drive partitioning is best done before installing any OS, by planning for the space beforehand. I feel it might cause some or all of your issues. If there was only one partition (besides Recovery) when Windows was installed, maybe it just can't know Linux exists, or something. To be honest, I didn't even know you could actually cut some space from a partition and give it to a new one without wiping everything.

-I don't know what results it gives to install a 32-bit and a 64-bit OS alongside. Sounds risky/buggy. Getting the 64-bit installer might just do magic.

If you don't want to format over again, you can try again with a 64-bit installation of Linux. If you have a restoration point prior to the installation attempt, go back there. If not, just delete whatever there is of Linux that you can find with Windows, and attempt to create a new partition again to install Linux.

If it doesn't work (and sadly I don't feel it will), if I were you, I would save my personal files somewhere (external hard drive for example) in plans of formatting. I really don't think you've corrupted the data that was already there. It should be very salvageable.

Then I'd reinstall Windows 8 on a set partition, creating the Linux partition in the same process. You could do that through the Recovery partition and/or DVD that came with your computer, maybe. Or the "Delete everything and reinstall Windows" option from the PC settings (open the Charms bar, Settings, PC settings (the very bottom thing), General) [approximate names; my computer is in French].

If none of those options allow you to format and manage partitions, then sadly, you'll have to find yourself the OEM install for your version of Windows, so it fits your product key that's probably coded inside your BIOS, from what I understand. This page might help you: http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-8-official-iso-images-and-product-keys-released-on-msdn-and-technet/

Alternatively, you can always buy Windows 8 over again. An OEM disc for Windows 8 Pro costs about 150 $, and can be bought notably from websites where you buy computer hardware, such as Newegg. But well, might as well try to find the right OEM disc download for your key. It's free and doesn't involve any piracy.

Anyway, once you've managed to install Windows 8 and set your partitions up, install Linux (64 bits!), and just have it format its own partition and install it there. Then everything should work perfect. On top, installing Windows clean over again and redoing your partitions yourself allows you to start fresh and free yourself of any useless software that might have come with the computer.

This link has issues similar to your own:
http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1730843

Comment: Thanks! Formatting without installing an OS wasn't an option; it had Windows 8 installed out of the box. I have no significant data on the system that I don't mind losing. The 32-bit installation was just a mistake on my part; I've already downloaded the 64-bit LM installer. I think I'll probably try the "Delete everything and reinstall Windows" thing (I hadn't yet figured out how to get to it). Can I assume that will fix up any partition problems?

Comment: Ok, I'm [reinstalling Windows](http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/492737/Nuke/) now. When that's done, I'll try booting from the live CD^H^H USB thumb drive; if the Linux partition no longer shows up, I should be in good shape.

Comment: Well, I've never tried that option from disc/basic options, but it should fix it. Just make sure you make your Linux partition during the installation of Windows. Don't wait until Windows is installed to create it.

Comment: Unless I missed something (which is quite possible), the Windows reinstallation didn't give me an opportunity to create partitions. BTW, the reinstallation *didn't* revert the partitions; now Windows sees my `C:` drive as less than 200 GB.

Comment: Okay, then... The sad scenario has occurred. It means you're going to need to download and burn the OEM disc of Windows that's appropriate for your installation. 'Tis the sadness of them not giving proper installation media with computers. :/

Comment: [This](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/shrink-and-extend-ntfs-volumes-in-windows/) suggests I may be able to expand the NTFS partition. I'll have to do some more research.

Comment: 32 and 64-bit OS on the same drive is not risky at all; it's not like they're running together and interacting in any way. @KeithThompson: Since your C partition is now 200GB, looks like the Mint installer *did* partition the drive after all. If you have Win8 up and running, try expanding the system partition using Disk Management. If that fails, just use GParted to accomplish this.

Comment: To be honest, I fear this would still cause issues. You can always try, though. But personally, when something is messed up, I prefer to start over instead of fiddling around to fix it.

Comment: See the update to my question. I'm not sure I should accept your answer, since it wasn't actually the solution I used. I'd give you a second upvote instead if I could. 8-)}

Comment: Glad you were able to dix it, though a bit sad you had to use another drive for it. :/

Comment: @Ariane: I probably didn't have to, but I feel better having the two OSs on separate drives anyway.

Comment: You can also install Mint like a regular Windows compatible application using Mint4Win.  Mint4Win is included in the Mint LiveCD.  The OP didn't state why he wanted both OSs, but the performance hit is nominal and it makes it easy to try out Mint for awhile.

Comment: @OCDtech: The machine is primarily a Linux box; I'm only keeping Windows because I might *occasionally* use it. (If I had a Windows installation disk, I'd consider wiping out Windows and then installing it in a VM under Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall Linux and make sure [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) goes in the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), not the Linux partition. Windows won't recognize Linux, but Linux will recognize Windows so by putting GRUB in the MBR you will get the GRUB menu at boot to pick your OS.

That said, there are other, more involved, ways to do this without re-installing Linux, but since you have no data on the Linux partition to worry about, losing it's the easiest way.  Also, since you are using the pre-installed Windows 8, you need to make sure Windows secure boot is not going to prevent anything because of [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface). I don't use Windows 8, so I haven't dealt with this, but I am aware it's a potential roadblock.